# Storing tweets in DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, twitter, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I'm storing tweets in `DynamoDB`. I'm using the tweet's `id` property for the hash key and the tweet's `created_at` property for the range.

I want to query on all the tweets in the table to find all tweets after a particular date. I gather that I need to make a `GSI` (Global Secondary Index) for the `timestamp` property of the tweet, so that I can query for all tweets after a particular date without needing the tweet's `id` property. Is this true? And if so, did I do this properly: (I'm confused as to why I need to specify a hash key *and* a range key for the GSI?)

[image]

Comment: You don't have to have a Range key for a GSI.

Comment: @garnaat So I should do `number` for my `Index Hash Key`, name the `Index Hash Key` timestamp, and then don't specify an index range key? It's just confusing since the `Index Name` field has a `*`...

Comment: The ``Name`` is simply the name you want to give to this index which you will need to use when querying against it.  I would choose something like timestamp-index.  You can have the timestamp itself as the Index Hash Key and, since GSI's do not require unique index keys you could even have multiple items with the same timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to create a range index on an attribute in DynamoDB. Tough luck as this is not what the author had in mind. I'll explain.

DynamoDB wants items to be [distributed evenly across hashes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload) and to have uniform load. Your twitter_id hash key is definitely helping but is failing you when you want to ask questions about your range keys.

You see, if you want speed - you want to [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) stuff as Query = index and Scan = no index. Query requires a hash key to query on - you can't query without one.

You are correct that you can't use your original primary key for this and you are correct thinking about `GSI` - You can *by pass* the hash key by creating a GSI that will have a constant hash* and timestamp as range.

BUT

If you do that you are breaking DynamoDB's performance by having an index with no distribution. This can cause you headaches in scale and generate bad throughput (you'll pay for more than you'll consume).

I put a star on constant hash* because you can do some manipulations to create several hashes and combine them in application level.

To conclude, it is possible to do what you want with Dynamo, but it is not a good fit for Dynamo.